# Click on Facebook LikeView returns "Application is not visible to this person" exception

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using facebook-android-sdk v4.4.0 and I'm trying to implement the like button in my Android app. I did everything "by the book": in my activity's `onCreate` I'm doing the following:

```
mLikeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
mLikeView.setObjectIdAndType(url, LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);
mLikeView.setOnClickListener(this);
mLikeView.setOnErrorListener(new LikeView.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    });
```

And after in my activity's `onActivityResult` I'm calling the `mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Like button is shown but whenever I click it, I get a blank Facebook page that closes almost instantly and I get a "Application is not visible to this person" FacebookException. Like button is still under review and I'm the administrator of the Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out why this was happening. It was the wrong application id. I found out this by uninstalling the Facebook app from the phone and by letting the WebView to do it's job when I got the error message with the app id it tried to connect to. Apparently Android Studio cached the old app id.